# Laravel-Backpack Getting data of 2 tables by join

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-backpack

I'm new using backpack for laravel and I'm trying to understand how could show data from DB in the default view that backpack use to display rows. I already read the documentation from the site but it's really poor, and have a lot of questions.

I have 2 models linked by join, for example:

```
Table 1                 Table 2
-id                      -id
-name                    -phone
-age                     -description
-table2_id
```

How can I display the attributes from table 2 in table 1 list view?. Backpack haves this view to list elements of modules

[image: backpack-list-view]

I want to see on that table the combination of the 2 tables...Any code that could help me ?. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Backpack creates CRUD Panels for you Eloquent Models. Not your database tables. So in order to have columns showing up that show elements from another table, you need to [properly define the relationships between those Models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships). Then you can [use the select column](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/3.4/crud-columns#select) to show that connected entry.

Answer (score 0):

```
  [
            'name'  => 'rm_id',
            'label' => 'Relationship Manager',
            'type'  => 'select2',
            'model'=>config('permission.models.role'),
            'options'   => (function ($query) {
                return $query->where('roles.name', 'Relationship Manager')
                    ->join('model_has_roles', 'model_has_roles.role_id','=','roles.id')
                    ->join('users', 'model_has_roles.model_id','=','users.id')
                    ->select('users.id','users.name')->get();
            }),
            'attribute'=>'name',
        ],
```